# WatchKit Long Look: how to start content from underneath the Sash?

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit

I found following text in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1) about WatchKit's Long Look (the detail view of a push notification):

> The content area ... For custom interfaces, you can configure this area to start underneath the sash or just below it.

How to start the content from *underneath* the sash? I'd like to partially overlap an image with the sash, but couldn't find any options for that (could only layout all my content below the sash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the watchkit forums over at developer.apple.com there was a discussion about this topic. It's removed from beta 5 by design and that's all we know right now.

edit: I found out how to get this to work!

Select the "Static Notification Interface Controller"
Change the color field

[image: Color Field]

Comment: Does it mean that overlapping is no longer possible? Do u still have the link to the thread?

Comment: Thx! It looks like this feature has been removed indefinitely from WatchKit (according to answers by Apple guys in the Apple forum)

Comment: It seems so. However, the demos that were shown during the keynote all had the content underneath the sash.. I imagine this is a setting that we've overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

This is good question and...I can't answer it directly.
The thing is: if you download Xcode Beta 4, content will start from underneath the Sash.
However in Xcode Beta 5 it starts from below lower edge of sash. Don't know whether it's a bug or feature.